# `df.select_dtypes` works with `float` but not `int`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just came across this strange behaviour of `pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes`.

My `pd.DataFrame` is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'c': [1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8]})
```

Now if I want to select the numeric columns, I would do:

```
df.select_dtypes([int, float])
```

But the the output only contains the `float` column:

```
     c
0  1.2
1  3.4
2  5.6
3  7.8
```

Why is that? I listed both `float` and `int`, why doesn't it list the integer column.

Here are the `dtypes`:

```
>>> df.dtypes
a      int64
b     object
c    float64
dtype: object
>>>
```

As you can see, they're both end with `64`, but only `float` works.

More tests:

```
>>> df.select_dtypes(int)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> df.select_dtypes(float)
     c
0  1.2
1  3.4
2  5.6
3  7.8
>>>
```

Why does this happen?

---

I know I could just do:

```
df.select_dtypes(['int64', 'float64'])
```

But I want to know the reason for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need all integers and all float columns check [`numpy types`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

It means `int16`, `int32`, `int64` match `integer`, same principe for floats:

```
print (df.select_dtypes(['integer', 'floating']))
   a    c
0  1  1.2
1  2  3.4
2  3  5.6
3  4  7.8
```

Reason: Found [`numpy types`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html):

> **Warning**

> The **int_** type does not inherit from the **int** built-in under Python 3, because type int is no longer a fixed-width integer type.